# formatting a string

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have the following code, which generates insert queries

```
For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(d)
    objSQLStringBuilder.Append("insert into table1 (full_path, file_name) values ('" & f.Replace("'", "''") & "', '" & f.Remove(0, Len(d) + 1).Replace("'", "''") & "');")
Next
```

However, the paths which it finds are formatted as follows

```
c:\program files\microsoft office\winword.exe
```

I need to format the paths as follows

```
file:///c:/program%20files/microosoft%20office/winword.exe
```

How can I modify the above code to do this?

Comment: Its never a good idea to "generate insert queries" especially using user input

Comment: I know, but it's an intranet environment, so no real risk of anyone trying to hack into it.

Comment: Even in your intranet: just **DON'T** do it ! Use parametrized queries - **ALWAYS!** - no excuse accepted.

Comment: It's not just hacking protection - it's performance (the engine can cache the execution plan), robustness (the app won't break if you don't escape something perfectly).  There's a reason everyone is suggesting it - if you've followed that pattern before it's almost unthinkable to use the string concatenation approach!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As m.edmondson pointed out, you're much better off using command parameters.

Here is the basic idea:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (full_path, file_Name) values (@full_path, @file_name)";

param = new SqlParameter("@full_path", varchar, 255);
param.Value = fullPath;

//add param for file name

command.Parameters.Add("@full_path");

command.ExecuteNotQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't write your SQL in this way if at all possible - try and use a SqlCommand object with parameters. That helps in two ways:

- takes care of the quote / space
  escaping etc
- helps guard against SQL
  injection attacks

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to that format by writing `new Uri(path).AbsoluteUri`.

As everyone else mentioned, **use parameters**!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how the query is related to your question. Seems more like a distraction to me.

At any rate, you can use s.Replace(" ", "%20").

You can also use HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s) but that will encode characters other than just the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is as simple as continuing what you were already doing with *string*.Replace(*string*, *string*) calls:

```
   For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(d)
        objSQLStringBuilder.Append("insert into intranet.dbo.noticeboard (full_path, file_name) values ('" & "file:///" + f.Replace("'", "''").Replace(" ", "%20").Replace("\", "/") & "', '" & f.Remove(0, Len(d) + 1).Replace("'", "''") & "');")
    Next
```

Also, that is a bad way to write SQL as others have mentioned.